# How do you add a comment to an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: stack-overflow, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

When viewing a question on Stack Overflow, there are answers that can be voted on, but an answer can also have a multiple comments from different users.

How do you add a comment to an answer on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a minimum level of reputation (50, I believe), and the question cannot be locked by the admins (or community).

Answer (score 1):

[You need to have at least 50 rep to comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) but you're not quite there yet.

Comment: And folks can help by up-voting his question.  He can help by picking an answer.

Comment: That won't make a difference once this question gets migrated to meta.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger - Generally, it's advisable to only upvote well-researched questions, but of course, people are free to vote as they please.

Answer (score 1):

A reputation of 50 is what you need and look at if the post you want to comment is closed then you can't comment.

Comment: @GregJF have i answered you?